# изменить путь открытия phpmyadmin по умолчанию ( linux )

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache, phpmyadmin

изначальние условия( сервер Apache, ОС linux Ubuntu)
Задача стоит следующая: 
1.нужно создать виртуальных хост
2. чтобы на етом виртуальном хосте по умолчанию открывался phpmyadmin(без приставки /phpmyadmin)

первую часть я уже сделал. есть виртуальных хост он открывается по адресу http://igor
осталась вторая задача. в конфигах пока не нашел решения. Спасибо

Мои настройки VirtualHost:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@phpmyadmin.localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/phpmyadmin.localhost
    ServerName phpmyadmin.localhost
    ServerAlias www.phpmyadmin.localhost
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Что мне прописать в DocumentRoot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обратите внимание на дерективу `alias`

Нужно сделать примерно вот так:

```
Alias /php444my333admin888 /usr/share/phpmyadmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
///// any code
</Directory>
```

**UPD** Не дочитал вопрос...

В директивах виртуального хоста, подготовленного для phpmyadmin, используйте `DocumentRoot` соответствующий пути к phpmyadmin

**UPD2**

У автора видимо неверно настроены стандартный виртуальных хост и тот хост, который работает с phpmyadmin.

Если соблюдать нижеследующие условия, то работать всё должно как надо:

1. Нужно исключить из настроек `Alias /phpmyadmin`, но перенести дерективу, начинающуюся с `<Directory /*****>` в новый виртуальный хост.
2. Убедится, что обращение к серверу по IP адресу показывают default виртуальный хост, а при обращении к http://igor открывается вновь созданный.
3. Прописать новый виртуальный хост с такими настройками:

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>   ServerName igor
>   DocumentRoot ПУТЬ_ДО_ФАЙЛОВ_PHPMYADMIN
>   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/pma-error.log
>   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/pma-access.log combined
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

Comment: если в Alias прописать другое значение, например /phpmyadmin.localhost  то phpmyadmin будет открываться по адресу igor/phpmyadmin.localhost т.е просто поменяется имя обращения. В моем случае нужно задать чтобы при открытии igor/  (корень) открывался phpmyadmin

Comment: Для этого я написал UPD: замените в `<VirtualHost *:80> ServerName igor` значение `DocumentRoot` на дирректорию phpmyadmin

Comment: значение DocumentRoot я так понимаю нужно указать как /etc/phpmyadmin/ или как то по другому (я просто новичек в linux разбираюсь, поетому прошу прощения за такие уточнения)

Comment: вот конфиг виртуального хоста phpmyadmin.localhost
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@phpmyadmin.localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/igor/phpmyadmin.localhost
        ServerName phpmyadmin.localhost
        ServerAlias www.phpmyadmin.localhost
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
вот настраиваю под директорию phpmyadmin.localhost, подскажите пожалуйста что нужно прописать в документ рут

Comment: Поправьте вопрос и оформите код, так будет понятнее.

Comment: переписал и оформил вопрос в ссылке http://pastebin.com/kQyk3hhn сдесь нельзя отформатировать.

Comment: Да! действительно в документРут поставил адрес /usr/share/phpmyadmin теперь стало открыватся phpmyadmin по умолчанию!  спасибо