# Как закрыть страницу доступа к PHPmyAdmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

Всем привет.

PHPmyAdmin доступен по адресу: http://181.45.26.12/phpmyadmin

Как сделать так, что бы он был не доступен по данному адресу.
Но при этом попасть в PHPmyAdmin можно было по другому адресу известному только мне.
Например: http://181.45.26.12/qwertyAdmin

P.S.
Выделенный сервер на Ubuntu. Nginx+Apache. MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Открываем файл `/etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf` .Ищем существующий  Alias и меняем на свой

Приример:

```
Alias /qwerty1213/ /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/
```

После этого не забываем перезагрузить апач

```
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

Тема кстати уже [подымалась](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/429572/%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-phpmyadmin-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-linux)

Comment: Спасибо. Но. Получается у PHPmyAdmin два адреса. Алиас http://181.45.26.12/qwertyAdmin не запрещает обращаться сюда http://181.45.26.12/phpmyadmin

Comment: Алиас не решает задачу.